# How To Undo Changes In Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: uninstall, synaptic

I was trying to uninstall Python then reinstall it because some files from it were missing. When I clicked apply changes it uninstalled it started uninstalling things like Firefox, Compiz and other important programs. The bar on the buttons on the top left corner changed, Firefox's and Dash Home's logo changed into a question mark. How do I undo these changes.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In synaptic go "File" > "History". Find where you did this & put back the packages removed that you want.